# how to get each nth element from a range till last?

Tags: ruby

I do have a range like `(1..10)`. Now I want to get every third element from the range. For the given range here I want as a output: `[4, 7, 10]`.

any short one liner?

Comment: `(1..10).find_all { |i| i < 10 && i % 3 == 1 }`

Answer (score 8):

Nice short form for you:

```
(1..10).step(3).drop(1) #=> [4, 7, 10]
```